# use variable to determine the name of a column in the select in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, select, dynamic-sql, scripting

I'm trying create a update for a new structure of tables from a old table, but not using functions. I'm trying create a script to it.
The old table is like this:

Old table (`OldTable`)

| name | col_a | col_b | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 | NULL | 1 |
| DEF | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| GHI | NULL | 1 | 0 |

And, the new tables:

`Users`:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | DEF |
| 3 | GHI |

`Rules`:

| ID | RULE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | col_a |
| 2 | col_b |
| 3 | col_c |
| 4 | col_d |

`UserRule`

| ID_USER | ID_RULE |
| --- | --- |

So, I'm needing populate the table UserRules with the result from a select on TableMix where the user name is equals to the user name on table User and the value for column <col_name> in TableMix is equals 1. (select <col_name> from OldTable where OldTable.name = Users.name).
Well, I'm trying this:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE rules CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name   = 'OldTable' 
        AND data_type = 'numeric' AND column_name NOT IN ('foo','bar'); 
        -- "foo" and "bar" are another numeric cols, but not define rules.
    DECLARE users CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM public.Users;
    BEGIN
        FOR ruleName IN rules LOOP
            FOR userName IN users LOOP
                EXECUTE format('SELECT COALESCE(%I,col,$1) FROM public.OldTable 
                    WHERE name = ''$2''', ruleName, username);      
                -- insert on... populate the table Rules after get the id of the rule in table Rules if the result of select in OldTable equals 1 (or true if has a "where ... = 1")
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
END $$
```

After this, I don't have progress.

**UPDATE**

This way I can get the real value:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    rules CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name   = 'oldtable' AND data_type = 'numeric'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('foo','bar');

    names CURSOR FOR SELECT username FROM public.users;

    res integer;
BEGIN
    FOR rulename IN rules LOOP          
        EXECUTE format('SELECT %s FROM oldtable WHERE nome = %L', rulename, 'USER NAME')    INTO res;
    -- IF res > 0 THEN
       RAISE NOTICE '%', res;
    --END IF;
    END LOOP;
END $$
```

Result the real integer value.

But if I use a loop for usernames, it's doesn't work.

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    rules CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name   = 'oldtable' AND data_type = 'numeric'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('foo','bar');

    names CURSOR FOR SELECT username FROM public.users;

    res integer;
BEGIN
    FOR name IN names LOOP
        FOR rulename IN rules LOOP          
            EXECUTE format('SELECT %s FROM oldtable WHERE nome = %L', rulename, name)   INTO res;
        -- IF res > 0 THEN
           RAISE NOTICE '%', res;
        --END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END $$
```

So, the result is always .
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Copied and pasted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26122833/398670

Comment: PS: The first error occurs because the column name is printed with parentheses. "SELECT (<col_name>) from ...."

Comment: Yes, because there are people who are not in both groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `USING` clause:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT COALESCE(%I,col,$1) FROM public.TableMix 
                WHERE name = $2', ruleName)
        USING (username, whateverTheSecondParameterIs);
```

You use `$1`, `$2`, etc for placement-parameters, passed by `USING`. You use `%I` for itentifiers expanded by `format`.

Update: If you want to coalesce the column name `ruleName` if it's null, perhaps you want something more like:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM public.TableMix 
                WHERE name = $1', coalesce(ruleName, 'col'))
        USING (username);
```

??

You need to think about order of evaluation. What's part of the generated SQL, and what's evaluated in order to create that SQL?

Comment: Thanks! But the initial problem persist: column name is printed with parentheses. "SELECT COALESCE(<col_name>) from ...."

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Hang on, are you trying to coalesce the column name, i.e. "if the column name is null, use the column name `col` instead"? If so, you have to do that *outside* the dynamic SQL string, in the `format` argument list.

Comment: pfff!! Yes man! Just the obvious... :) Sorry guys,  after a while I could not see the obvious... And, I do not even know pgsql  (yet). :(
Now... how get the result and progress this work? I no have idea how to do this without giving a lot of laps.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo `EXECUTE ... INTO`. See the pl/pgsql manual, "dynamic SQL" section.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Probably best accept this answer if it's helped then, and follow up with a new question if you're stuck on something else later.

Comment: Not really. But mark it to close the topic.